# Can somebody identify what part is being used as a vase in this picture?

Tags: part-identification

[image]

I'm not even sure if it's Lego.  I'm quite the novice, so... little help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be part [30106 Minifigure, Utensil Crystal Ball Globe 2 x 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30106).

[image]

It has a small indentation on top, which is probably how they were able to balance it in that picture.

Comment: I didn't see that coming :)